# How to connect nodes very fast using shortcut?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, shortcut

In ***Compositing nodes*** window there is an option to quickly connect the *selected node* to a *viewer node* using some kind of keyboard shortcut. I can't remember what it was. The only thing I remember is, that you have to hover the cursor over the active node's output (as shown below), press RMB or LMB and some kind of shortcut. Thanks for help in advance.
[image]

One other thing is interesting to me. When I hover the cursor over the selected node's output and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Right-click</kbd> it become highlighted. What is this kind of selection for?
[image]

Comment: Consider the Node Wrangler addon. It is now included in Blender 2.72 trunk, enable like any other addon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Click</kbd> on the node and it will connect to the viewer node. If no viewer exists, it will create one.

You can also select two different nodes and press <kbd>F</kbd> to connect them automatically (they will try and connect from the first output to the first input if they are available).

The <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Click</kbd> (or right-click as you mentioned) on the node socket output allows you to select which specific node sockets are connected when using <kbd>F</kbd>. This means you can also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Click</kbd> on the target node socket to select which input it will connect to (by default it will connect to the next free input on the node).

Comment: Not at my pc right now but almost sure it's **LEFT** click? and it will connect to the viewer node, on subsequent triggers, it will iterate though all the other outputs.

Comment: Thanks Ray! Your answer fully satisfy me:). Before I'll check the accept button I have to know last thing. The CTRL+SHIFT+Right-click doesn't work for me. I have to do it with Left-click. Is it the matter of computer you use?

Comment: @Gonzou Nope, just me getting a bit confused :) Just forgetting which button I have assigned to my stylus. Left-click is correct

Answer (score 5):

You can connect 2 or more nodes together by their primary input and output socket using <kbd>F</kbd>. Additionally, you can add a node between two nodes by just dragging it over the noodle (the line) connecting them.